# How to get subList values in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have following method where I am trying to compare two text files.

So basically I need to compare `substring` of `sourceFile` line with the `generatedFile`.
Here I am struggling with getting value of the subList. Because I thought of doing substring after getting the value.

```
def FileCompare(String sourceFile, String generatedFile) {
   def firstList = new File(sourceFile).readLines()
   def m = 0
   def n = 1

   new File(generatedFile).readLines().each {
      println  firstList.subList(m,n)
      println  it.substring(0,8)
      m = m + 1
      n = n + 1

      // more coding to be done for compare  
   }
}
```

Above `println firstList.subList(m,n)`  I can see the result as `[2104808660                   COMPANYX]`

But the intention is to `substring` that.

**sourceFile**:

```
2011070620110707             COMPANYX            
2104808660                   COMPANYX
2104808662                   COMPANYX
2114454303                   COMPANYX
2114454303                   COMPANYX
00000004
```

**generatedFile**:

```
2011070620110707             COMPANYX            
2104808665                   COMPANYX
2104808661                   COMPANYX
2114454301                   COMPANYX
2114454301                   COMPANYX
00000005
```

Comment: Please illustrate data from the input files and clarify the expected output.

Comment: @MichaelEaster added to the question. As appears there `2104808660 ` and `2104808665 ` is not tallying.(second line) So I wanted to check that part(this is fixed lemgth) of the entire string and get the failure assertion in my automation test.

Comment: a sublist of [n,m] with m=n+1 is the same as just firstList[n].  then call your substring on that and you should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What You can do is to read content of both files to two lists and compare the lists:

```
def toList(filename) {
   new File(sourceFile).readLines().collect { it[0..7] }
}

def sourceList = toList(sourceFile)
def generatedList = toList(generatedFile)

//comparison
```

Answer (score 2):

So you would to extract first 8 characters of each line from both files? Take a look at example:

```
def firstList = new File(sourceFile).readLines()

new File(generatedFile).readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->

    println  firstList[index].substring(0,8)
    println  line.substring(0,8)

    // ...or even shorter with ranges:

    println  firstList[index][0..7]
    println  line[0..7]

    // more coding to be done for compare  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to save the file lines for other tasks then you could try this.

```
[new File(sourceFile).readLines(), new File(generatedFile).readLines()]
    .transpose().each{ line ->

    println line[0][0..7]  //Line from sourceFile
    println line[1][0..7]  //Line from generatedFile

    // compare code here.
}
```